# how to add Follow or create Friendship using Fabric sdk

Tags: twitter-follow

how to add Follow or create Friendship using Fabric sdk for twitter android app
here is the link
https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/index.html
i am unable to get information from fabrics docs for follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the answer
Actually its required end point to be made for the api calls which is not available already

```
public class TwitterFollow extends TwitterApiClient {
        public TwitterFollow(TwitterSession session) {
            super(session);
        }
        public FollowService getFollowService() {
            return getService(FollowService.class);
        }

        /*interface used for Auth Api call for CreateFriendship*/
        public interface FollowService {
            @POST("/1.1/friendships/create.json")
            public void create(@Query("screen_name") String screen_name, @Query("user_id") String user_id, @Query("follow") boolean follow, Callback<User> cb);
        }
    }
```

and then using it

```
TwitterFollow apiClient = new TwitterFollow(session);
apiClient.getFollowService().create(TWITTER_ACCOUNT_NAME, null, true, new Callback<User>() {
                            @Override
                            public void success(Result<User> result) {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks for following!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Error following", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service methods cannot return void. while using this code for follw

Answer (score 0):

@SunilRaikwar, create method must have **Call<**User**>** as return value and not as parameter :

```
public class TwitterFollowApi extends TwitterApiClient {

    public TwitterFollowApi(TwitterSession session) {
        super(session);
    }

    public FollowService getFollowService() {
        return getService(FollowService.class);
    }

    /*interface used for Auth Api call for CreateFriendship*/
    public interface FollowService {
        @POST("/1.1/friendships/create.json")
        Call<User> create(@Query("screen_name") String screen_name, @Query("twitterLike") boolean follow);
    }
}
```